# Kotlin: Firestore: Looking through an Any? variable that has an array as its value

Tags: kotlin

When looking up a document in Firebase Firestore, I get back an Any? variable. The actual structure in that variable is a map that looks like this:

`{words : [mary, had, a, little, lamb]}`

I know that because I can look into Firestore, and Timber prints the Any? variable that way. I want to put that array in a Set (I don't care for the key). Below is the only way I managed to get it to work, but it looks ugly (esp. that loop: there's always only 1 element...) Is there a cleaner way?

Thank you!

```
// document is the Any? var I get back from Firestore
val words = (document as? HashMap<*, *>)?.values
if (words != null) {
    for (word in words) {
        lyricsSet = (word as? List<*>)
            ?.filterIsInstance<String>()
            ?.toSet()
            ?: emptySet()
    }
}
```

BTW, the words variable looks like this:
`[[mary, had, a, little, lamb]]`
I'm not sure how/why the singleton list of the list I'm trying to get to was created.

Comment: Can't you just access to the value in the hashmap ?

Comment: Nope... it's an "Any", so document.value gets upset ("unresolved reference"), as does words[0] ("no get method providing array access").  ...take(1) didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `document` is a `HashMap<List<String>>` typed as `Any?`.

```kotlin
var document: Any? = hashMapOf("words" to listOf("mary","had","a","little","lamb"))
```

You used [HashMap.values()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/values.html), which gives you a list of the HashMap<K,V>'s value (`MutableCollection<V>`). And each value itself is a list (`V is List<String>`). That's why you get a nested list (`MutableCollection<List<String>>`).

So to access the `List<String>`, you should access the HashMap value directly by the key "words".

If you don't care unchecked cast (you 100% confident that document is not any type else), you could write

```kotlin
lyricsSet = (document as? HashMap<String, List<String>>)?.get("words")?.toSet() ?: emptySet()
```

Or if you need absolute type safe:

```kotlin
lyricsSet = ((document as? HashMap<*,*>)?.get("words") as? List<*> )?.filterIsInstance<String>()?.toSet() ?: emptySet()
```

Comment: Nest the "as?" operations -- brilliant. Both of these work like a charm. Thank you also for clarifying the nested list mystery!